# How to override admin template with layout, how to get reference block

Tags: magento2, overrides, phtml

I want to override below templates. I tried with placing core layout in my custom module and place template in same directory structure.

Can any one please tell me where I am making mistakes.

Templates:

```
1) adminhtml\templates\sales\invoice\create\items\renderer.phtml

2) adminhtml\templates\sales\invoice\view\items\renderer.phtml

3) adminhtml\templates\sales\creditmemo\create\items\renderer.phtml

4) adminhtml\templates\sales\creditmemo\view\items\renderer.phtml

5) adminhtml\templates\sales\shipment\create\items\renderer.phtml

6) adminhtml\templates\sales\shipment\view\items\renderer.phtml
```

Layouts I placed in my modules are:

```
=> adminhtml_order_shipment_new, => adminhtml_order_shipment_view, => sales_order_creditmemo_new, => sales_order_creditmemo_view, => sales_order_invoice_new, => sales_order_invoice_view.
```

In Layout Code is like

```
<referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <block class="Magento\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Items\Renderer" as="bundle" template="sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Can any one please tell me what is the correct way to override this template.

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass template name with your custom module name like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="order_items">
        <block class="Magento\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Items\Renderer" as="bundle" template="Vendor_Module::sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Flush cache and try.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but its not working